# Converting list to array with NumPy asarray method

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x, numpy

I try get mean from csv line. I get data from csv in string list, further i convert it to array with numpy. Its work perfect when i try plot some graphics.
But when i calculate mean i get some errors with my data.

If i use NumPy i get:

```
TypeError: cannot perform reduce with flexible type
```

If i use statistics library i get:

```
TypeError: can't convert type 'string' to numerator/denominator
```

If i check my array with comand 'type' on iPython i see that it numpy.ndarray type.

Whats wrong with my array? Can you explain, why convert numpy.asarray for matplotlib work perfect, but get wrong type for different operation.

```
import csv
import numpy as np
import statistics as stat
life_exp=[]
with open('country.csv') as csvfile:
   datareader = csv.reader(csvfile)
   for row in datareader:
    if datareader.line_num!=1:
        life_exp.append(row[1])
array_life_exp = np.asarray(life_exp) 
print(stat.mean(array_life_exp))
print(np.mean(array_life_exp))
```

Comment: Can you provide some lines from your csv?

Comment: @VladMironov Its simple example from OpenIntro Statistics book. Afghanistan,49.72,121.63,4 
Albania,77.59,14.12,45. I take a second number of each row. (49.72 from first line, and 77.59 from second etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
from pandas import read_csv

data = read_csv('country.csv')
print(data.iloc[:,1].mean())
```

This code will convert your csv to pandas dataframe with automatic type conversion and print mean of the second column.

Comment: It work for me like magic. But whats wrong with NumPy? It needs me for plotting charts. Do you not, why don't work .asarray converting for me?

Comment: data.iloc[:,1] is np.array :)

Comment: Because numpy convert all your elements to str:
`In [144]: np.asarray(['1',23,'4.'])
Out[144]: array(['1', '23', '4.'], dtype='<U2')`

Comment: Thank you.I promise to read the documentation on this method:)

Comment: You're welcome! Check dtype value in [np.asarray](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.asarray.html)

Comment: for my code when i insert in iPython array_life_exp, it shows me dtype='<U5'. Мay be the reason for this?

Comment: numpy automatically choose most volume type. In your case it's 5 char string. So avoid np.asarray (np.array is pretty nice tho) or at least recheck it.